# If statement always goes into else code, even when conditions should be true

Tags: vb6

I am giving below condition in vb.6 and my Obj1.Id=7777 however it is always going in else part. Please advice.

```
If Obj1.ID <> Null And obj1.ID <> "" then
    str1="UPDATE"
Else
    str1="INSERT"
End IF
```

Comment: How do you set the value of Obj1.ID?

Comment: I am fetching from DB

Comment: Have you debugged into the code to ensure the value you're fetching really is 7777?

Comment: yes It is the same value

Comment: Is there any another way to check object values comparison?

Comment: You could split your `if` into two separate lines, i.e. `If Obj1.ID <> Null Then If obj1.ID <> "" then`, and see which one is causing the problem.  It could be an issue with the way the column is defined in the DB, not allowing `NULL` values , or a type mismatch problem.  If Obj1.ID is an integer, and you're comparing to an empty string, that could be a problem.

Comment: ID type in DB is Varchar(8)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the `<>` operator and `null`. Nothing equals or does not equal Null in VB6 You have to use the `IsNull` function:

```
If Not IsNull(Obj1.ID) And obj1.ID <> "" then
```

You can also check if it's Nothing:

```
If Not Obj1.ID Is Nothing And obj1.ID <> "" then
```